# Web API GET that takes optional parameters that can have multiple values for the same named parameter

Tags: c#, api, get, optional-parameters

I need to develop a new web API GET that will have multiple optional parameters along with 2 parameters that will not be optional. The optional parameters can have multiple values for the same name. For example, the following parameters can have several values at the same time with one api call: 
State, PaymentType, PaymentSource.

The non optional parameters would be FromDate and ToDate.

The optional parameters will be populated from user selected values from a front end UI list boxes. So for example the State listbox will have all states listed as selectable options. So if the user selects 10 states then the optional State parameter for the API needs to contain all 10 states as a value for that parameter. The same will be true for the other optional parameters as well.

I have never done this before so I'm not sure how or if this can be done. All APIs that I have experience with only had a single value for each parameter. How can these parameters for my API be created this way ? should they be a list ?

Comment: Why don't you use a separated parameter for each listbox?

Comment: Each parameter will have its own associated list box . So for example State will be a listbox with 50 possible values that can be passed to the API in the State parameter. The question I have is how to pass the 0 - 50 possible values for the State parameter.

Comment: Have you tried using a List<>?

Comment: after doing some more research I believe I will need to change my design to be an HTTP Post API so that I can pass the complex type in the body of the request. it seems that only primitive types are allowed in the uri of a GET.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
[Route("api/foo/{State}/{PaymentType}/{PaymentSource}/{FromDate?}/{ToDate?}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] List<string> State, [FromUri] List<string> PaymentType, [FromUri] List<string> PaymentSource, [FromUri] List<string> FromDate = null, [FromUri] List<string> ToDate = null)
{ ... }
```

The query string parameter should be of this format

```
~/api/foo?State[]=value1&State[]=value2&PaymentType[]=...
```